# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services - Configuring the Unattended Account - Invalid domain\alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis, dns

I'm trying set up an execution account following the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx

I follow these steps:

1. Start the Reporting Services
   Configuration tool and connect to
   the report server instance you want
   to configure.
2. On the Execution
   Account page, select Specify an
   execution account.
3. Type the account
   and password, retype the password,
   and then click Apply.

I've tried the following accounts but always getting the same error below.  administrator, ASPNET, SYSTEM.  I tried these accounts alone, and also with prefixing them with LOCALMACHINE/ or computer name/

(One problem is I'm not sure the passwords are for the second two accounts.)

Here is the error I get:

```
ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.WMIProviderException: The account name is not valid. Specify an account in the form domain\alias.
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.SetUnattendedExecutionAccount(String userName, String password)
```

I'm on Windows XP pro, and I'm not on a domain, it's just this one computer.  Here's my system info:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  9.00.3042.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 2005.090.3042.00
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the user comments, it says

rsconfig -e -uMYDOMAIN\MyUserName -pMyPassword

I agree: I've never seen fwd slash

Comment: Whoops.  Thanks.

LOCALMACHINE\ASPNET worked with leaving the passwords blank.